# How to Call Func to Other Func in Swift

Tags: swift

How to call variable in func to add another func

example

```
func firstFunc () {
  let number = 100
}
```

and I want to call number to secondFunc

```
func secondFunc () {
  *I want to call number from firstFunc to here*
}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: You can use return in firstFunc

Comment: do you mean you want to pass a parameter into a function?

Comment: func firstFunc (){
    let number = 100
    
    return
}

func secondFunc (){
    print(number)
}

like this ?

Comment: i want to call number to secondFunc from firstFunc

Comment: func secondFunc (number:Int) {
   print(number)
}

Comment: you need value of number from firstfunc?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a function finishes executing (returns), all the local variables declared in it becomes inaccessible. Therefore, accessing `number` from `secondFunc` without changing `firstFunc` is impossible.

There are a few ways you can do this, depending on your situation and your ultimate goal.

1. Return:

   ```
   func firstFunc () {
       let number = 100
       return number
   }

   func secondFunc() {
       print(firstFunc()) // 100
   }
   ```
2. Pass as parameter:

   ```
   func firstFunc () {
       let number = 100
       secondFunc(parameter: number)
   }

   func secondFunc(parameter: Int) {
       print(parameter) // 100
   }
   ```
3. Inner function:

   ```
   func firstFunc () {
       let number = 100
       func secondFunc() {
           print(number) // 100
       }
       secondFunc()
   }
   ```
4. Return, then pass as parameter:

   ```
   func firstFunc () {
       let number = 100
       return number
   }

   func secondFunc(parameter: Int) {
       print(parameter) // 100
   }
   secondFunc(parameter: firstFunc())
   ```
5. Make `number` global:

   ```
   var number = 0
   func firstFunc () {
      number = 100
   }

   func secondFunc() {
       print(number) // 100
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't just want to set `number` as a class-level variable, which would you could access directly in `secondFunc`, you could try this

```
func firstFunc() -> Int {
    return 100
}

func secondFunc () {
    *I want to call number from firstFunc to here*
    let otherNumber = firstFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use return in firstFunction or

```
func firstFunc () {
  let number = 100
    func secondFunc () {
        print(number)
    }
}
```

other way is:

```
func firstFunc () -> Int{ 
    let number = 100
    return number
}

func secondFunc () {
   print(firstFunc) //you will get value of number in firstFunc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. Class variable or pass the variable to the next function.

**Example 1**

```
var number = 100

func firstFunc () {
  number = 100
}

func secondFunc () {
  number = 2000
}
```

**Example 2**

```
func firstFunc () {
  var number = 100
  secondFunc(number: number)
}

func secondFunc (var number:Int) {
  number = 2000
}
```